# bind a topology to a blender sculpture

Tags: modeling, sculpting, topology, retopology

I made a sculpture of a head and then its topology, now I would like to know how to link them so that the culture is in the sculpting mode of the topology?

Comment: What do you mean here with "a topology"?

Comment: I presume by "topology" you mean "retopology"? But about the "sculpting mode", I don't know what you mean. Do you want to bake your sculpture onto the retopology?